# Java regex not replacing properly

Tags: java, regex

Below is a code snippet where I want to replace few strings. I am using date_add pattern two places in my code, but its getting replaced only once.I am using string.replaceAll but still its not working for me. Please help me identifying the reason.

```
public class Implementation {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String ipquery = "select  to_date(id)  from location_dim location_dim where ( location_name  =  '123' ) limit 10 union all select  item_id  " +
        "item_id  from  (select item_dim.time_id from item_dim item_dim where item_dim.time_id in  (  select time_dim.id from time_dim " +
        "where (( time_dim . day ) = date_add( '1999-01-01' ,  2 )) ) ) item_dim inner join time_dim  time_dim  on (( item_dim . time_id ) " +
        "= ( time_dim . id )) where (( time_dim . day ) = date_add( '1999-01-01' ,  2 )) limit 20";
   System.out.println(replace(ipquery));

 }

public static String replace(String query) {
  Map<String, String> imputnmatch = new HashMap<String, String>();
  imputnmatch.put("to_date", "date");
  imputnmatch.put("format_number", "format");
  imputnmatch.put("date_sub\\((.*),\\s*([0-9]+\\s*)\\)",
      "date_sub($1, interval $2 day)");
  imputnmatch.put("date_add\\((.*),\\s*([0-9]+\\s*)\\)",
      "date_add($1, interval $2 day)");
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : imputnmatch.entrySet()) {
    query = query.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " + entry.getValue() + "   " +query);
  }
  return query;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `"date_add\\((.*),\\s*([0-9]+\\s*)\\)"` pattern `.*` will try to find maximal potential match, so it will try to find part which will start with `date_add\\(` and will end with `,\\s*([0-9]+\\s*)\\)` which means that in data

> select  to_date(id)  from location_dim location_dim where ( location_name  =  '123' ) limit 10 union all select  item_id  item_id  from  (select item_dim.time_id from item_dim item_dim where item_dim.time_id in  (  select time_dim.id from time_dim where (( time_dim . day ) = date_add( '1999-01-01' ,  2 )) ) ) item_dim inner join time_dim  time_dim  on (( item_dim . time_id ) = ( time_dim . id )) where (( time_dim . day ) = date_add( '1999-01-01' ,  2 )) limit 20

it will match

> select  to_date(id)  from location_dim location_dim where ( location_name  =  '123' ) limit 10 union all select  item_id  item_id  from  (select item_dim.time_id from item_dim item_dim where item_dim.time_id in  (  select time_dim.id from time_dim where (( time_dim . day ) = date_add( **'1999-01-01' ,  2 )) ) ) item_dim inner join time_dim  time_dim  on (( item_dim . time_id ) = ( time_dim . id )) where (( time_dim . day ) = date_add( '1999-01-01'** ,  2 )) limit 20

To make `.*` search for minimal match you need to make `*` quantifier reluctant ([lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)) by adding `?` after it. So try with

```
"date_add\\((.*?),\\s*([0-9]+\\s*)\\)"
//             ^-add this
```

Same rule apples for `date_sub\\((.*),\\s*([0-9]+\\s*)\\)` pattern, which means you need should change it to  `date_sub\\((.*?),\\s*([0-9]+\\s*)\\)`

Answer (score 1):

you are using .* that also include ")" so your one date_sub is include in date_sub pattern. so change your date_sub & date_add pattern [It will help you](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)